# Automated test-bench, Matlab or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, unit-testing

I have a system, let's say a product firmware that has to be tested on its embedded platform. For this I can access the platform using a C library and I will need to control some instruments (function generators, multi-meters, oscilloscopes) to get some measurements.

To be more specific regarding my application, let's imagine I would like to check that the firmware of a parallel robot is perfectly working. Apart from the independent unit-tests inside the firmware source-code, I will need to do more tests that involve physical feedback. I can for instance measure the pressure of a arm against a sensor or measure the back EMF voltage. Some of these tests are critical (that means the overall testing procedure will fail with no second chance). Some other are not only pass-fail, they can raise a warning and the test can continue.

Because some routines are implemented in low-level C, they are part of the API that I am addressing with Matlab/Python. So these routines may fail and I will have to catch the error code into a try/catch.

At a different level, my test can be also broken in some ways. If a failure occurs, I would like to log the complete trace-back. Which test unit, which class instance, which method and which API function.

I have found two technologies that seem to be very suited to be used for that purpose: Matlab and Python. With both I can access C dlls, I can plot graphs and I can control instruments over a VISA port.

To write the series of tests in python I can use a combo of `unittest`, [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) and `logging`.

In Matlab it seems the existing packages are very poor. I have found [log4m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37701-log4m-a-powerful-and-simple-logger-for-matlab) and Matlab2015 provides native functions for unit testing. However, my feeling is that Python is a bit more adapted for what I am trying to do.

I have to say I already have plenty of Matlab licenses and money is not an issue in this case.

I recently discovered that Matlab and Python offer both interfaces to talk to each others. Also, I've read that these two technologies are becoming very popular for testing purposes.

I would like to find solid arguments and concrete examples that will help me to find the right technology.

My current feeling is that Matlab will not give me any help to automate my test-bench with for instance external hooks on Git/ClearCase repositories. Bulding an HTML report and getting a good traceback information is not easy to achieve.

Is it possible to get good traceback information, nice logger accross my modules, and test classes that can be triggered by an external script in matlab?

Comment: This question is quite off-topic. Also you should provide some more concrete information. The first thing which came to my mind was [**Simulink**](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/index.html), which is a very powerful tool, which can't be substituted by Python, but it's usefulness depends on how you plan to implement *function generators, multi-meters, oscilloscopes* etc. And what about LabView? Not a "real" programming language though, but from your description it appears to be a good choice as well.

Comment: For evaluating Matlab you could join the [Matlab Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave) to get some ideas, as the question is to broad.as it is. I'm also working with Python, the coding itself is more intuitive than with Matlab, but when it comes to big datasets (tables, text files, csv files) and its postprocessing (plots etc.) I find Python to be really pain in the a** compared to Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tough to say without gathering more details on your specific use case and learning more how you are setting up your environment. Just looking at what you are using in python we have the unit test framework, a logging framework, and an HTML test runner.

As you say, MATLAB we have the unit test framework and it itself has logging features ([1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.loggingplugin-class.html),[2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase.log.html)). Can those be used?. There is not (yet) have an HTML report, but you can:

1. Use the  [XMLPlugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.xmlplugin-class.html) to produce JUnit style xml and perform an XSLT to create html from it.
2. Plug in to a CI system using either JUnit or TAP and these systems typically have reporting capabilities. An example of doing this with Jenkins is [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/01/20/the-other-kind-of-continuous-integration/) and [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/01/29/tap-plugin/).

Ultimately, the CI system links do so how to run your tests automatically, and I can tell you that there has been and continues to be a very large investment in the diagnostic (i.e. traceback) information provided by the unit test framework. The logging features in the framework are catered to test logging rather than inter-module logging so I am not sure if that will work for what you would like, but there is also log4m like you say.

Comment: Thank, I like your answer. You showed me some directions to explore and this is what I am expecting. As you asked, I just updated my question and gave a more specific example about my application. Hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: Yes it does clarify, and it sounds like the features you need are all in MATLAB as well. Are you using logging to provide the "warnings" cases that don't fail the test? If so you may just be able to call testCase.log(1, 'Something went wrong') to record that information. Alternatively if you want to fail the test but continue testing MATLAB's framework is ideal for you because you can use verifications (e.g. testCase.verifyEqual(1,2)) rather than assertions which fail and return early. MATLAB's verifications allow failures while still continuing the test.

Comment: Also, I failed to mention before, but the CI system workflows supported by MATLAB's framework (in the blog example) can listen to source control changes in Git/Clearcase and can kick off the testing sessions.

Comment: Another comment, you mentionned **CI system** which is the exact term I was looking for since the beginning. I am trying to build a [Continuous Integration system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) that check the changes on the source control, rebuild the sources and test them.